# Property is optional in type but required in type

Tags: typescript

I am creating a mock generator. The builder works well if all properties are required, but when a property is optional the typing informs `'Property 'address' is optional in type 'MyType' but required in type'`

Note: this code has been reduced for this example, the builder generates fields, string, number, date, array, objects.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ncbzty?file=index.ts)

```
type BaseType = string | number | boolean | Date | unknown;

type MockType<T> = Record<
  keyof T,
  | BaseType
  | BaseType[]
  | Record<string, BaseType | BaseType[]>
  | Record<string, BaseType | BaseType[]>[]
>;

export class MockBuilder<T extends MockType<T>> {
  private mock = {} as MockType<T>;

  private static randomString(
    length: number,
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
  ) {
    let result = "";
    for (let i = length; i > 0; i -= 1)
      result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
  }

  private static getRandomFromArray<A>(array: Array<A>) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  }

  private static fillFieldString(fieldContent?: Array<string>) {
    return fieldContent === undefined
      ? MockBuilder.randomString(16)
      : MockBuilder.getRandomFromArray(fieldContent);
  }

  withString(fieldName: keyof T, fieldContent?: Array<string>): MockBuilder<T> {
    this.mock[fieldName] = MockBuilder.fillFieldString(fieldContent);
    return this;
  }

  build() {
    return this.mock as T;
  }
}

type MyType = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  address?: string;
};

const mock = new MockBuilder<MyType>()
  .withString("firstName")
  .withString("lastName")
  .withString("address")
  .build();
```

In doing `const mock = new MockBuilder<Required<MyType>>()` optional properties become required and the error is gone. But I want to correct it in the builder's parameters, not in the instantiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `class MockBuilder<T extends MockType<T>>`, now the `T` is equal to `MockType<T>>`.

Why not use `class MockBuilder<T>` instead? and then the error will be gone.

Comment: So easy and I wasn't seeing it, thank you very much